# Is there a way I can see a list of all the applications I've set as "default"?

Tags: default-applications

I've accidentally set some applications as "default" in the past, but I currently do not remember which ones. Is there a way to get a list of all applications that have defaults that I can clear? Going through each individual application in the install applications list would be quite a chore.